# Error package arrowR : "TProtocolException: Exceeded size limit" - Is it possible to read the parquet file

Tags: r, parquet, apache-arrow

Following [this question in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77982801/error-package-arrowr-read-parquet-open-dataset-couldnt-deserialize-thrift-t) relating to this error :

```r
Error in `open_dataset()`:
! IOError: Error creating dataset. Could not read schema from 'path/example.parquet'. 
Is this a 'parquet' file?: 
Could not open Parquet input source 'path/example.parquet':
Couldn't deserialize thrift: TProtocolException: Exceeded size limit
```

**I'm wondering if there is any way to still be able to use the parquet file, even though the schema is oversaturared by attributes ?**
This situation would occur when the script that produced the parquet file was deleted, or it would cost a lot of time to ask/provide a cleaner parquet file.

I already tried to used the partitioning option but the error still occured, no matter how many variables I used to partition it.

#### Repex :

```r
library(arrow)
library(data.table)
# Seed
set.seed(1L)
# Big enough data.table 
dt = data.table(x = sample(1e5L, 1e7L, TRUE), y = runif(100L)) 
# Save in parquet format
write_parquet(dt, "example_ok.parquet")
# Readable
dt_ok <- open_dataset("example_ok.parquet")
# Simple filter 
dt[x == 989L]
# Save in parquet format
write_parquet(dt, "example_error.parquet")
# Error
dt_error <- open_dataset("example_error.parquet")
```

Comment: it seems you got an solution of using `thrift_string_size_limit` over at https://github.com/apache/arrow/issues/40050

Comment: Yes, I wanted to document this issue + solution on SO so that people could find it ((https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), but I can only post every 30 min

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentionned in the [gitlab issue](https://github.com/apache/arrow/issues/40050), adding the parameter `thrift_string_size_limit` makes it possible to read the parquet file. **Please note that the parquet file's size is still very much saturated**.

```r
dt_error <- open_dataset("example_error.parquet", thrift_string_size_limit = 1000000000)
```